# Using "youtube-transcript" to get captions from youtube videos

Tags: youtube

I was trying to use [youtube-transcript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-transcript) to get captions from youtube videos. It worked well in single js or ts file. But when I use it in a Next JS project it just don't work.

Below is my code and the error I got.

```js
import { YoutubeTranscript } from "youtube-transcript";
YoutubeTranscript.fetchTranscript("QY8dhl1EQfI").then(console.log);
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [YoutubeTranscript]  TypeError: URL is not a constructor
    at new YoutubeTranscriptError (youtube-transcript.esm.js:74:1)
    at Function.eval (youtube-transcript.esm.js:134:1)
    at step (youtube-transcript.esm.js:64:1)
    at Object.eval [as throw] (youtube-transcript.esm.js:45:46)
    at rejected (youtube-transcript.esm.js:36:42)
```

The expected result I run in js file

```json
PS C:\Users\warren\Desktop\Training\tsnode> node test.js
[
  {
    text: 'what is going on everyone my name is',
    duration: 2800,
    offset: 399
  },
  {
    text: "anson and in this video i'm going to go",
    duration: 2960,
    offset: 1680
  },
  { text: 'ahead and teach you', duration: 2801, offset: 3199 },
  { text: 'how to', duration: 3440, offset: 4640 },
  { text: 'call the youtube data api', duration: 4400, offset: 6000 },
  {
    text: 'to get specific information from youtube',
    duration: 3599,
    offset: 8080
  },
  ...
```

Can someone explain to me what can I do to avoid the error?
 Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

This package does not work on the Client Web (React CRA). Only works on backend.  If you need to use this package in a client-side application, you may need to look for alternatives that are compatible with frontend environments or consider implementing the functionality you need on the backend and exposing it to your frontend application via APIs.
Below code is of Next JS App router

```
import { YoutubeTranscript } from 'youtube-transcript';

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const url = searchParams.get("url")!;
  try {
      const transcript = await YoutubeTranscript.fetchTranscript(url);
      return Response.json(transcript);
  }
  catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return Response.json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
  }
}
```